# Data structure to hold and retrieve points in a plane

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

**Definition 1:** Point (x,y) is controlling point (x',y') if and only if x < x' and y < y'.

**Definition 2:** Point (x,y) is controlled by point (x',y') if and only if x' < x and y' < y.

I'm trying to come up with data structure to support the following operations:

- Add(x,y) - Adds a point (x,y) to the system in O(logn) complexity, where n is the number of points in the system.
- Remove(x,y) - Removes a point (x,y) from the system in O(logn) complexity, where n is the number of points in the system.
- Score(x,y) - Returns the number of points (x,y) controls - number of points that (x,y) is controlled by. Worst case complexity O(logn).

I've tried to solve it using multiple AVL trees, but could not come up with elegant enough solution.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that a good enough data structure exists?

Comment: Yes, this question appeared in my exam on data structures few days ago. The question was worth 15/100 points so it must have relatively straightforward solution.

Comment: One insight that you may be able to use is that the score of a point (x,y) is `(# of points (a,b) (with a > x) + (with b > x) - (with a <= x) - (with b <= y)) / 2`. Note that this only works as-is if your points are unique.

Comment: That `b>x` should be `b>y`

Comment: This was the idea behind my solution but it required 4 AVL trees to keep up with desired complexity. I was wondering if a more elegant solution exists.

Comment: :(:(:(:( if you've made progress on your own, you should post it in the question.

Comment: I think you can manage it with two slightly enhanced AVL trees though. You make one AVL tree where each node has an x-coord and a set of y-coords, and another where each node has a y-coord and a set of x-coords. And in both you make sure that each node contains the size of the subtree rooted at that node.

Comment: In case it wasn't clear above, I meant size of the subtree, taking multiplicity into account.

Comment: Yeah I did understand that. I will try to think in that direction.

Comment: the forumula above doesn't work; consider x,y = 2,2 and points a,b of 1,1 and 3,3.  The formula yields 0, but should be 1.  (Compare this to a,b of 1,3 and 3,1 where 0 is the correct answer.  The formula doesn't distinguish between the two sets of points)

Comment: Are you hinting that "Inclusion–exclusion principle" can't be used to solve this problem?
Don't put too much significance on the exact formula.

Comment: not in a way that's obvious to me, no.  I too started with balanced binary trees -- it's easy to get the count of (x < a) and (y < b) (binary trees annotated with subtree size), but I don't see a way to get the count of the intersection of the two sets (or of their complements, same thing here).  Maybe quadtrees (ie 2-d k-d trees) could work, I don't remember their O() cost.

Comment: not sure, but looks like calculating Score() on a quadtree might be O(sqrt n) and not log n.  This is from eyeballing a picture, not from a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> Point (x,y) is controlling point (x',y') if and only if x < x' and y <
>   y'.
>
> Point (x,y) is controlled by point (x',y') if and only if x' < x and
>   y' < y.

Lets assume that (x,y) is the middle of the square.
(x,y) is controlling points in B square and is being controlled by points in C.

The output required is the number of points (x,y) controls minus the number of points (x,y) is being controlled by. Which is the number of points in B minus the number of points in C,`B-C`(Referring to the number of points in A,B,C,D as simply `A,B,C,D`).

We can easily calculate the number of points in `A+C`, that's simply the number of points with x' < x.
Same goes for `C+D` (Points with y'y), `B+D` (x'>x).
We add up `A+C` to `C+D` which is `A+2C+D`.
Add up `A+B` to `B+D` which is `A+2B+D`.
Deduct the two: `A+2B+D-(A+2C+D) = 2B-2C`, divide by two: `(2B-2C)/2 = B-C` which is the output needed.

(I'm assuming handling the 1D case is simple enough and there is no need to explain.)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of future reference

**Solution outline:**

We will maintain two AVL trees.

- Tree_X: will hold points sorted by their X coordinate.
- Tree_Y: will hold points sorted by their Y coordinate.

Each node within both trees will hold the following additional data:

1. Number of leaves in left sub-tree.
2. Number of leaves in right sub-tree.

For a point $(x,y)$ we will define regions A ,B, C, D:

- Point (x',y') is in A if x' < x and y' > y.
- Point (x',y') is in B if x' > x and y' > y.
- Point (x',y') is in C if x' < x and y' < y.
- Point (x',y') is in D if x' > x and y' < y.

Now it is clear that Score(x,y) = |C|-|B|.
However |A|+|C|, |B|+|D|, |A|+|B|, |C|+|D| could be easily retrieved from our two AVL trees, as we will soon see. 
And notice that [(|A| + |C| + |C| + |D|) - (|A| + |B| + |B| + |D|)]/2 = |C|-|B|

**Implementation of required operations:**

- Add(x,y) - We will add point (x,y) to both of our AVL trees. Since the additional data we are storing is affected only on the insertion path and since the insertion occurs in (logn), the total cost of Add(x,y) is O(logn).
- Remove(x,y) - We will remove point (x,y) from both of our AVL trees. Since the additional data we are storing is affected only on the removal path and since the removal occurs in (logn), the total cost of Remove(x,y) is O(logn).
- Score(x,y) - I will show how to calculate $|B|+|D|$ as others done in similar way and same complexity costs. It is clear that $|B|+|D|$ is the number of points which satisfy $x' > x$. To calculate this number we will:

  1. Find x in AVL_X. Complexity O(logn).
  2. Go upwards in Tree_X until the root and on each turn right we will sum the number of elements in left sub-tree of the son. Complexity O(logn).

  Total cost of Remove(x,y) is O(logn).